# How to inject SharedPreferences to a ViewModel using Dagger2 in android java

Tags: android, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences, viewmodel, dagger-2

I am facing a problem while trying to inject SharedPreference to a ViewModel, I am doing the dependency injection using dagger. I will add the main sections of the code below

Module SharedPreferencesModule.java

```
@Module
public class SharedPreferencesModule {

    private Context context;
    public SharedPreferencesModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    public SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
        return this.context.getSharedPreferences("login",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```

Sub Components are added as given below

```
@DashScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = {
        DashboardFragmentBuildersModule.class, D
        ashboardViewModelsModule.class,
        DashboardModule.class,
        SharedPreferencesModule.class // Added Newly for injecting
        }
)
abstract DashboardActivity contibuteDashboardActivity();
```

The error I am getting is given below

> error: @Subcomponent.Factory method is missing parameters for required modules or subcomponents:

I understood that the constructor in the SharedPreferencesModule is cauing the error and since the module is added using ContributesAndroidInjector, I cannot able to pass a context to the SharedPreferencesModule. But I need that to get the SharedPreferences

Is there any way to ge rid of this issue.

My BaseApplication code is given below

```
public class BaseApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The reference for the development is from this link [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qZh6Fyrz-k&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8AOAspC3DHoBNZIBHbIOsC)

Any help would be much appreciated, Since I had spend a whole day with this.

Note : Any alternate solution I can use, but I cannot break this project structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have two contexts in your Dagger graph: `Application` and `DashboardActivity`.  To use one of these, simply add it as a dependency in your `@Provides` method.  (If you use `DashboardActivity`, I would suggest using a `@Binds` method to bind it to `Activity` or `Context` first.)

For example, to use the `Application` binding already in your graph:

```java
@Module
public class SharedPreferencesModule {

    @Provides
    public static SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return application.getSharedPreferences("login",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you brother, you saved my day :)   One question: Does this solution keeps the MVVM architecture without any memmory leaks ?  @nitrodon

Comment: Yes, you can use this module class in any app architecture, including MVVM.  Also, `SharedPreferences` is safe to store anywhere, and this module isn't storing it anyway, so there's no risk of a leak.

Comment: Okay Thank you!  One more thing , could you please add the other way of using `Context`  through `@Bind` and `DashboardActivity`